# NTP time sync over PROXY

Tags: proxy, ntp

I have a machine that is on a network with a proxy server... The ntp sync fails to go through the proxy, how can I make it go through?? What configuration is needed on my machine?? does it necessary require any configuration in the proxy server?

Comment: An HTTP proxy should have no bearing whatsoever on your ability to sync NTP.

Comment: all the network traffic goes through it, not just HTTP

Comment: Then it's not a proxy, it's a router.

Comment: Configure your NTP client for the network's NTP server. If the network doesn't have a NTP server, set one  up. If you are a user and not the system administrator then this site is not for you, see the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup NTP on the proxy server to sync with the wider world and tell the isolated machine to use the proxy for NTP service.